# How to convert a string into a nested hash

Tags: ruby

I have a string `foo.bar.baz` with a value 'qux' that I want to convert to a nested hash like so:

```
{
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: 'qux'
    }
  }
}
```

How would I do this in a way that would allow for different string lengths? e.g. `foo.bar` or `foo.bar.baz.qux`

Comment: By creating a recursive method. What have you actually attempted?

Comment: Your String has a value of "foo.bar.baz" I am not sure where "qux" comes from?

Comment: @engineersmnky Sorry, should have been more clear. `foo.bar.baz` represents an AR object's property and `qux` would be the value of the property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#split-method) the string. You can then use [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#inject-method) to build the structure. Because the hash is built from the inside out, we have to [`reverse`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#reverse-method) the initial array:

```
'foo.bar.baz'.split('.')  #=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
             .reverse     #=> ["baz", "bar", "foo"]
             .inject('qux') { |memo, key| { key.to_sym => memo } }
#=> {:foo=>{:bar=>{:baz=>"qux"}}}
```

It might not be obvious how this works. On the first invocation, `memo` is `'qux'` and `key` is `'baz'`. The block turns this into `{:baz=>'qux'}` which then becomes the new `memo`.

Step by step:

```
memo                    key                result
--------------------------------------------------------------
'qux'                   'baz'                  {:baz=>'qux'}
{:baz=>'qux'}           'bar'           {:bar=>{:baz=>'qux'}}
{:bar=>{:baz=>'qux'}}   'foo'    {:foo=>{:bar=>{:baz=>'qux'}}}
```

Comment: I prefer the alias `reduce` over `inject`. Because `reduce` is used more in other languages, people will recognise/understand it earlier. It also better describes what is happening imo. A collection of values is reduced to a single value.

Comment: I don't know how you got such a good idea! It's a brilliant one!

Comment: You could use the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes one argument and no block in place of `String#split` and [Array#reverse_each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse_each) in place of `Array#reverse` to return enumerators, avoiding the construction of the temporary arrays `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` and `["baz", "bar", "foo"]`: `'foo.bar.baz'.gsub(/[^\.]+/).reverse_each.reduce ('qux') { |memo, key| { key.to_sym => memo } }`.

Comment: ....We obtain `enum = 'foo.bar.baz'.gsub(/[^\.]+/) #=> #<Enumerator: "foo.bar.baz":gsub(/[^\.]+/)>` and `enum.reverse_each #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator:"foo.bar.baz":gsub(/[^\.]+/)>:reverse_each>`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland beautiful.